# I am not sure why I am getting an error for this simple code in a jsp file

Tags: java, html, jsp

[this is the error that comes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuTMG.png)
 I have tried several things to make it work but i cant seem to figure out the issue. This portion is the part that decides whether or not the login was successful and the error is in the part where the login succeeds and it outputs and posts the username for use on the next page. the error is specifically on this line `<%=out.print(idnum)%>` Edit: the line got cut off for some reason when it posted apologies. I also added the entirety of the code, don't mind the obvious security issues it isn't important for what I'm working on

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        //user variable declarations
        String idnum = "";
        String pwd = "";

        String user = request.getParameter("user");
        String password = request.getParameter("pwd");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/assignment2", "root",
                "1234");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT * from users where idnum = '" + user + "'";
        //out.println("Query: "+query);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        //get idnum and password for checks
        while (rs.next()) {
            idnum = rs.getString("idnum");
        }
        query = "SELECT * from users where idnum = '" + user + "'";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            pwd = rs.getString("password");
        }
        if (pwd.equals(password)) {
    %>
    </br>Welcome 
    <form action="BuyTicket.jsp" method="post">
        <%=out.print(idnum)%>
        <input type="submit" text="Buy Tickets" />
    </form>

    </br>
    <%
        } else {
    %>
    </br>Invalid Username or Password please try one of the following
    </br>
    <a href="Login.html">Login</a>
    </br>
    <a href="Register.html">Register</a>
    </br>
    <%
        }
    %>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm confused. Is this meant to be PHP or Java?

Comment: Well, you cut out the useful information that would let us see what line the error is on... Why post a screenshot when you could just copy and paste the text?

Comment: no idea what that is, but, by pure logic, shouldn't any `%>` be paired with an opening `<%`? (3rd line) And posting errors messages as a link and to an image - so hard to read

Comment: @spork its in the title its a jsp. the section of code is java in the jsp.

Comment: @LowKeyEnergy apologies it got cut off when posting for some reason. I put the line back in as I intended

Comment: @Toonlord yep, now that you've removed "this simple code *in this PHP file*" in your last edit, your question makes more sense.

Comment: Why was this thread closed? we are still discussing it @Sotirios Delimanolis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an opening `<%` for the expression where your if statement starts.  Try this:

```
<%=out.print(idnum)%>
<%
    if (pwd.equals(password)) {
%>
    </br>Welcome 
    <form action="BuyTicket.jsp" method="post">
        <%=out.print(idnum)%>
        <input type="submit" text="Buy Tickets" />
    </form>

    </br>
<%
    } else {
%>
    </br>Invalid Username or Password please try one of the following
    </br>
    <a href="Login.html">Login</a>
    </br>
    <a href="Register.html">Register</a>
    </br>
<%
    }
%>
```

Comment: It is a snippet of the code. I can post the whole code if that would be more helpful. It has all the needed tags for the jsp just the java code isn't working

Comment: Sure you can post it.  Basically, you need to balance all of your scriplet tags, when you want to write java code it has to go between `<%` and `%>` tags.

Comment: added all the code

Comment: I don't think you need `out.print` where you have `out.print(idnum)`, that is a JSP expression which prints to the output so you should be able to just do `<%= idnum %>`

Comment: didn't realize that works thanks